# Symfony 2 Doctrine 2 Attempted to call an undefined method named "getName" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to do a fetch associated objects as shown in documentation symfony 2. It shows me an error like title this post. what I doing wrong ?

```
public function indexAction( )       


{

$UserRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserUserBundle:User');
 $all = $UserRepo->findOneBy(array('username'=>'macq'));
 $allOwner = $all->getOwner()->getName();

    return array(
    'allOwner'=>$allOwner,
     );
}
```

}

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *      targetEntity ="User\UserBundle\Entity\User",
 *      inversedBy ="owner"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *      name = "user_id",
 *      referencedColumnName ="id",
 *      
 * )
 */
protected $user;


**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity ="Property\ManagementBundle\Entity\Owner",
 *      mappedBy ="user"
 * )
 */
protected $owner;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's rather self-explicable.

Assuming that you want for each user to have many owners, you `User::$owner` class member does contain a `Collection` of `Owner` objects. Therefore, you cannot user `getName()` on that. If this is actually your intention you should name your class memeber `$owners` - that would greatly help you distinguish collections from persistent objects.

I believe you should have something like this:

```
class User{

    // ........

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity ="Property\ManagementBundle\Entity\Owner", mappedBy ="user")
     */
    protected $owners;

    // .........
}

class Owner {

    // ........

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity ="User\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy ="owners")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName ="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    // .........
}
```

And then your controller's code:

```
$UserRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserUserBundle:User');
$all = $UserRepo->findOneBy(array('username'=>'macq'));
$owners = $all->getOwners();

if ( $owners){
    $allOwner = $all->getOwners()[0]->getName();
}
```

Does this help?

I am still not convinced that your logic was not inverted. MY thoughts are that "`Owner` should contain many `User`s", not the other way around...